# Problems with extra vertical space and centering

Tags: horizontal-alignment, vertical-alignment

I have this generic "proof" concerning injections below and would like the vertical dots to be centered. I tried `\begin{centering}` but of course this adds vertical space above and below the dots which I would like to avoid. My MWE below uses `\centering` and I admit I may be using it incorrectly. When I attemtped this before with that centering command it worked fine **except** that it centered the entire proof.

I just want to center the vertical dots and nothing more with no extra spaces above and below those dots. Thanks!!!

```
\documentclass[12 pt]{article}
\usepackage[left=1.65cm,right=1.65cm,top=2.50cm,bottom=2.75cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amscd,amsbsy,array,color}
\usepackage{fancyhdr,framed,latexsym,multicol,pstricks,slashed,xcolor}
\usepackage{picture}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\usepackage[amsmath,framed,thmmarks]{ntheorem}

\theoremstyle{nonumberplain}
\theoremsymbol{\rule{1ex}{1ex}}
\def\theoremframecommand{%
\psshadowbox[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=red,linecolor=black]}
\newshadedtheorem{proof}{Proof}

\title{Analysis}
\author{Philip Dykes}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\begin{center}
    \textsc{Contrapositive Proof that $f: X \to Y$ is injective.}\\
    \begin{minipage}{8cm}
        \begin{proof}
            Suppose $x,y \in X$ and $x \ne y$.\\
            {\centering{$\quad \quad \quad \vdots$}} \\
            Hence $f(x) \ne f(y)$.\\
            $\therefore f: X \to Y$ is injective. 
        \end{proof}
    \end{minipage}
\end{center}


\end{document}
```

Comment: `\begin{centering}` is `\begingroup\centering` and would not add any vertical space (perhaps you meant `\begin{center}` ?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

centering is a paragraph setting, with the values at the end of the paragraph being use

```
            {\centering{$\quad \quad \quad \vdots$}} \\
```

there is no paragraph end there so `\centering` has gone out of scope by the time the paragraph ends

You could use

```
...\\
\makebox[\linewidth]{$\vdots$}\\
...
```

for example.

Comment: Thank you so very much David that works beautifully and exactly what I was looking for!!! I wish you and all here a very Merry Christmas and Happy Holidays!!!